# PKCS#11 and application identification

Tags: pkcs#11

In Cryptoki, all sessions that an application has with a token must have the same login/logout status. but how a token in a Network HSM can identify sessions related to an application? is there an application Id for this purpose? for example, by sending application id to each application after calling C_initailze and sending back id? There isn't anything about this in pkcs#11 spec. I want to implement pkcs11 for a network HSM. but i don't know how identify different applications in my cryptoki token.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PKCS#11 defines an API usually implemented via the dynamically linked library. In run-time (when loaded) the library becomes the part of the process and gets requests from that process. So the library knows the ID of the process that it serves. Now it's up to you how your PKCS#11 library and your hardware communicates. Possibly you can store the process ID somewhere along the data passed to and from the hardware.